# AWS lambda with Annotation framework

Tags: c#, .net, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-serverless

How do you test your lambda endpoints locally with postman without uploading them to AWS? I have an endpoint attributed like below.

```
[LambdaFunction()]
[HttpGet("hello/{prompt}")]
public string Hello(string prompt, ILambdaContext context)
{
   return prompt.ToUpper();
}
```

Once I started 'Mock Lambda Test Tool', I tried on my localhost with

`localhost:5050/hello/jim`

I got "Sorry, there's nothing at this address." then I tried

```
localhost:5050/api/hello/jim
```

same error

I tried changing the attribute

```
   [LambdaFunction()]
   [HttpApi(LambdaHttpMethod.Get, "hello/{prompt}")]
   public string Hello(string prompt, ILambdaContext context)
   {
       return prompt.ToUpper();
   }
```

Same error.

Didn't have any luck with Postman too. Am I missing any configurations or doing it wrong?

Any thoughts?